# Vaadin internationalization issue: java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm pretty new to Vaadin framework and I'm trying to make an internationalized application. I'm using NetBeans and I have followed these steps:

1. Create a new Vaadin project with a single UI class with a single
   text field on it.
2. I went to *Tools -> Internationalization -> Internationalization Wizard* and have followed those steps to internationalize the UI class.

Pretty simple. But when I run the application I get this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com/mycompany/i18ntest/Bundle, locale es_AR
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:240)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

The exception suggests `Bundle.properties` file can't be found but it's present in the same package than UI class:

[image]

#### MyVaadinUI.java

```
package com.mycompany.i18ntest;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

@Theme("mytheme")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {

    private final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/mycompany/i18ntest/Bundle");

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class
                               , widgetset = "com.mycompany.i18ntest.AppWidgetSet")
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        TextField textField = new TextField(bundle.getString("MyVaadinUI.textField.caption"));
        textField.setRequired(true);
        textField.setRequiredError(bundle.getString("MyVaadinUI.textField.requiredError"));

        final FormLayout layout = new FormLayout(textField);
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);       
    }
}
```

#### Bundle.properties

```
MyVaadinUI.textField.caption = User
MyVaadinUI.textField.requiredError = Please input your user name here
```

---

Additionaly I've tried re-naming the `.properties` file to `Bundle_es_AR.properties` because my browser's default language is spanish (es) Argentina (AR), but no luck, still getting the exception.

Comment: Is the Bundle.properties also included in the WAR file?

Comment: No it's not! And I can't figure out how to make WAR file include it. I was inspecting all project properties options but I didn't find how to include this file on project deployment. @AndréSchild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AndréSchild [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484078/vaadin-internationalization-issue-java-util-missingresourceexception#comment34204486_22484078) (thank you) I realized the WAR file wasn't including `Bundle.properties`. After doing some Google search I have found how to include resources to Maven project by editing `pom.xml` file in [this article](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html). It presents two different ways to solve my problem:

#### Place .properties file inside resources folder

> By default, Maven will look for your project's resources under
>   `src/main/resources`.
>
> ```
> Project 
>    |-- pom.xml
>    `-- src
>        `-- main
>            `-- resources
> ```

This basically states that I could simply place `Bundle.properties` file inside `resources` folder and it will be included in WAR file.

[image]

This file will be located at the root of classpath so I have to do this change in `MyVaadinUI.java` class:

```
private final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle");
```

#### Add the folder as resource editing pom.xml file

If we want to add some resource which is not placed in `src/main/resources` folder we can edit `pom.xml` file adding a resource folder as follows:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[our folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

So in my case I could do something like this:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <directory>src/main/java/com/mycompany/i18ntest</directory>
     <includes>
       <include>*.properties</include>
     </includes>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

When WAR file is generated it will include the content of the specified resource folder (in addition to `/src/main/resources` fodler content) at the root of classpath. Once again I have to do this change:

```
private final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle");
```

***Note***: despite NetBeans shows all files in the resource folder, only `.properties` files will be included in WAR file because of this filter:

```
     <includes>
       <include>*.properties</include>
     </includes>
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of changing the getBundle, you can choose the targetPath atthe resource definition like this: `<resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/som/vaadin</directory>
                <targetPath>path/to/the/bundle</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>`